# DataGridView VB Celulas Editaveis

Tags: vb.net

Olá, possuo um DataGridView que é populado por um BindingSource e quando carrego os dados não consigo fazer a edição das Celulas com valore, apenas quando carrego o DataGridView vazio, tentei usar `DataGridView1.BeginEdit(True)` mas não funciona!

Codigo:

```
 Private Sub CarregarDataGrid()
    Try
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro ao Limpar o DataSource do DataGridView")
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    strsql = "select * from Usuarios"

    Dim objCommand As New MySqlCommand(strsql, conn)
    Dim dr_temp As MySqlDataReader
    Dim bs_temp As BindingSource = New BindingSource

    Try
        dr_temp = objCommand.ExecuteReader()
        bs_temp.DataSource = dr_temp
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs_temp
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Erro")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    confiDataGrid()
End Sub
```

Configurar DataGrid:

```
Private Sub confiDataGrid()
    If btnManutencao.BackColor = Color.Silver Then
        DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
        With DataGridView1
            Try
                .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Codigo Usuario"
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox("Erro")
                Exit Sub
            End Try
            .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Observações"
            .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Data Registro"
            .AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

gostaria de saber apenas como deixa-lo editável clicando na célula.
Desde Já agradeço!

Answer (score 1):

Tente adicionar a linha:

```
DataGridview1.ReadOnly = False
```

Depois que seu DGV é populado. Em base isto permitirá que o mesmo seja editado.